# SOAP/PHP : Complex Type as function param

Tags: php, soap, complextype

I am using a SOAP webservice and want to call a function that uses the `ComplexType` `EmailList` as parameter:

```
<xsd:element name="EmailList">
 <xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1024">
 <xsd:element name="Number" type="xsd:string" />
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here my code:

```
$wsdl = __DIR__ . '/wsdl.wsdl';

$emailList = ??? 

$service = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$service->sendMessage($emailList, "test", "mon message");
```

How do I declare the `$emailList` variable? (an array? `array("myemail.com")`)

Comment: use soapui to check how you need to send those parameters